# Set animation dynamically in Chart.JS

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chart.js2

I try to set [animation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/animations.html) dynamically in Chart.js. It should be either enabled or disabled based on some condition.

But it is always either enabled or disabled for some reason.

I've made a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vx48g01k/1/) to better describe my issue

[image]

Check out the code below:

```html
<div class="container">

   <button onclick="chart(true)">ANIMATION</button>

   <button onclick="chart(false)">NO ANIMATION</button>
    
   <div id="animation-info"></div>
 
   <canvas id="chart-container" width="300" height="200"></canvas>

</div>
```

```js
let animation = true
let CHART

chart(animation)


function chart(animation) {

  const anim_duration = animation == false 
  ? { duration : 0 }
  : { duration : 1000 }
  
  document.getElementById('animation-info').innerHTML =  `<br>Animation: ${animation} <br> Animation duration: ${anim_duration.duration}`

  
  // generate dataset with random values
  // random values are actual chart values here
  var dataset = Array.from( { length: 6 }, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1 ))
  
  var options = {
    type: 'doughnut',
   
    data: {
      labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
      datasets: [{
          label: '# of Votes',
          data: dataset,
          backgroundColor: [ "Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange" ],
          borderWidth: 1,
        }
      ]
    },
    options: {
       animation: anim_duration,
       cutoutPercentage : 60,
       responsive: true,
    }
  }
  
  var ctx = document.getElementById('chart-container').getContext('2d')


  if (typeof CHART == "undefined")
        CHART = new Chart(ctx, options)

  else {
        CHART.config = options  // updating with new chart data
        CHART.update()               // redraw the chart
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

#animation-info {
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Arial;
}

canvas { 
  opacity : 0.7; 
  margin-top: 20px;
}

button {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

I have also tried to set the option directly like

```js
Chart.defaults.global.animation.duration = duration
```

Seems to be the same issue.

---

I believe the issue is because I don't invoke `new Chart(ctx, options)` every time, but update chart configuration data only.

I do this to save resources because I rebuild the chart lots of times and invoking `new Chart(ctx, options)` every time seems to be a pretty heavy operation.

---

**Solution:**

As [LeeLenalee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8682983/leelenalee) suggested in his comment below adding

```js
CHART.options.animation.duration = animation == false ?  0 : 1000`
```

before `CHART.update()` did a trick

```js
if (typeof CHART == "undefined")
    CHART = new Chart(ctx, options)

else {
     CHART.config = options  // updating with new chart data
     CHART.options.animation.duration = animation == false ? 0 : 1000
     CHART.update()               // redraw the chart
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to set the options wrong. Both versions work. If you want to set it as default you will have to put it like this: `Chart.defaults.global.animation.duration = animation ? 1000 : 0`. You can also put it in your options object like this:

```
const anim_duration = { duration : animation ? 1000 : 0 }

options: {
  animation: anim_duration
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Leelenaleee/58pxb1j2/9/

EDIT after comment clarification:
Set the animation in your update method `CHART.options.animation.duration = animation ?  1000 : 0;` then call the update.

Comment: Thanks much for your answer @LeeLenalee.  It shouldn't be a syntax issue. Unless I am missing something my ternary operator syntax `var = condition ? x : y` is correct as well as yours.  I've updated my question with JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ur01n3ze/  to better describe my problem

Comment: yeah the reason I meant you set it wrong was more impliyied on the defaults, but also this way for your animation in my oppionion its a lot better readable and more DRY

Comment: I believe the issue is because I don't invoke `new Chart(ctx, options)` every time but update only config data. I do this to save resources because it seems to be a pretty heavy operation.

Comment: I have edited your fiddle so it will do what you want. In the update just override the duration with the correct one. To see it does it correctly I push a new dataset so you can see it animated or not according to the right button. https://jsfiddle.net/Leelenaleee/rj1nc4au/10/

Comment: Works perfectly! With the slight change to you fiddle `CHART.data.datasets = [ {} ]` this is exactly what I need. So basically I needed to set `CHART.options.animation.duration = animation ?  1000 : 0` before `Chart.update()` Thank you so much! Marked as accepted.